# Can any one help me, to create .apk file for google android market

Tags: file, google-play, apk

Please i am new to Android,  i dont know how to create apk file, to upload app in the market.  Please i need help, in step by step on how to create it. Am even ready for you to view my desktop and create it there for me if it will be possible, please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Following are steps,

1. Make an android market account
2. Go to the market.
3. Make sure your .apk file is signed as described in the manual.
4. Fill the details of your application and upload it.
5. Hit the Publish button and work done.

You can also see [link1](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html), [link2](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469).