# Android Publisher Account

Tags: android

I want to open an android publisher account. I want to know that should i open that from the india? if not than give the list of the countries which google allows to open an publisher account.

Comment: do you want to open an account for publish android application on market ?

Comment: if yes then it could be opened from india. just click on this link . https://market.android.com/publish/signup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better you donot open from India. Such an account will not be able to publish paid applications or applications with In App Billing

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy process. you can even google it.

However I have already it answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511625/can-any-one-help-me-to-create-apk-file-for-google-android-market/9511695#9511695).

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't it be allowed from India? Just sign up and activate your account via credit card for 25 dollars.