# Steps To deploy Android APK file into Android Market?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can any one help me, to create .apk file for google android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511625/can-any-one-help-me-to-create-apk-file-for-google-android-market)

I need Steps to Deploy our Application Into Android Market please tel me the process thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of things you need to do.
Signing Application,Providing Screen Shots,Icons,Information like category,Description,paid or free etc. Hard to explain all here.

Best link is this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Please go through all hyperlinks provide in this url.
If you have doubts regarding any specific point feel free to ask.